# PHP MySQL Database - All rows into Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

It's been a long while since I touched PHP so, I just need a refresher of sorts.

I have an HTML form that captures several lines of data (dataA, dataB, dataC & dataD) and inserts them into a database table (dataAll).  I will be entering rows upon rows of data into "dataAll".  What I'm looking to do is create a display.php page, where the code will take all of the data and place each cell into an array, or the row of an array, for example:

```
new Array = [["dataA", "dataA", "dataA", "dataA", "dataA"],
             ["dataB", "dataB", "dataB", "dataB", "dataB"],
             ["dataC", "dataC", "dataC", "dataC", "dataC"],
             ["dataD", "dataD", "dataD", "dataD", "dataD"]];
```

But I cannot remember the syntax on how to perform this task.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The database is named '*compdata*', the table is '*dataAll*', and each row is '*dataA*', '*dataB*', '*dataC*', '*dataD*'.

Please let me know if I need to supply more information.

Comment: Are you looking for : 
    Select dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD from compdata.dataAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for All rows, so the simple code for query is written below:

```
<?php
     //after connection to mysql db using mysql_connect()
     $sql = "Select dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD from `compdata`.`dataAll`" ;
     $result = mysql_query($sql) ;
     if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                  $dataArray[] = $row ;
            }
    } 
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($dataArray) ;//you got the desired 2D array with all results
?>
```

Comment: say I didn't know how many rows there were going to be in the end, would I just replace with: `$sql = "Select * from 'compdata'.'dataAll'" ;`

Comment: No problem with your query, BUT how many "rows" depends on LIMIT query not on "select *" or column names.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are used to the old mysql_xxx functions:

```
$data = array ();
$result = mysql_query ('select * from dataAll');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($restult, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    $data [] = $row;
```

Result:

```
$data = array (
    0=>array ('col_1'=>'dataA', 'col_2'=>dataB...),
    1=>array ('col_1'=>'dataA', 'col_2'=>dataB...)
);
```

If you only want the numbers and not the column names, use MYSQL_NUM.

However, mysql functions are being replaced with the more generic PDO object so you might want to look into that.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query ('select * from dataAll');
$result = $pdo->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    //  Or PDO::FECTCH_NUM
```

Same results as above.